# Как исправить отсуствие WebClient?

Tags: c#, сеть

Делаю скачивание файла на Windows Mobile в Visual Studio 2008 C# вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace LimonMarket
{
    public class FA
    {
        public void download(string fromfile, string to) {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(fromfile, to);

        }
    }
}
```

Пишет ошибку :
*Error 2 The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\stepa\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\LimonMarket\LimonMarket\FA.cs 12 13 LimonMarket
Error 3 The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\stepa\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\LimonMarket\LimonMarket\FA.cs 12 39 LimonMarket*

Comment: Какая у вас там студия, это особой разницы не дает, важнее тип проекта, и версия .NET, чего вы не указали. Ну и вообще, очень странный вопрос, вы используете древнейшую студию, используете OS, которая уже давно закрыта, и используете `WebClient`, который в C# устарел и на его место пришел `HttpClient`...